# How to prove that a complex function is not analytic in a rectangle?

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions, rectangles, analytic-functions

I have to solve the following exercice : "Let $a, b$ > be two positive numbers. Let $G(z)$ be a function such that $G(z+a) = G(z)$ and $G(z+ib) = G(z)$  for all $z$ in the complex plane. Suppose that $G(0) = 0$ and $G(a/2) = 1$. Show that $G$ can not be analytic in the rectangle that contains all the $z$ with $-a < Re(z) < a$ and $-b < Im(z) < b$"

For me, I can deduce that $G(z+a) = G(z-a)$ and $G(z+ib) = G(z-ib)$ so the contour integral around the rectangle must be $0$. Then, by the Morera's theorem, $G(z)$ has to be analytic...

I don't know where I did a mistake in my reasoning but if you have an idea or just a hint feel free to answer!

Comment: Morera's theorem requires continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ was analytic there, then it would be analytic in the smaller rectangle$$R=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,\operatorname{Re}(z)\in\left[-\frac a2,\frac a2\right]\wedge\operatorname{Im}(z)\in\left[-\frac b2,\frac b2\right]\right\}.$$Since this region is compact, $G|_R$ is bounded. And, by the two periodicity conditions on $G$, the image of $G$ is equal to $G(R)$. Therefore, $G$ is bounded and so, by Liouville's theorem, it is constant. But $G(0)=0$ and $G\left(\frac a2\right)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! But to use Liouville's theorem we have to make the assumption that G is entire. With your proof we can only conclude that G is not entire but it does not imply that G is not analytic on the rectangle. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Tonio Yes, you are wrong. Since the domain of $G$ contains the rectangle $\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,\operatorname{Re}(z)\in(-a,a)\wedge\operatorname{Im}(z)\in(-b,b)\right\}$, if it was analytice there then, because of the periodicity, it woud have to be an analytic function from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$. In other words, it would have to be entire.